# Sort decimal in PHP or MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I am developing a ledger application. My main problem is that my client has Chart of Account with code like this

```
1.1.1, 
1.1.2 
...... 
1.1.10, 
1.1.11,
.........
```

Using PHP or MySQl I can only manage to sort them to

```
1.1.1, 
1.1.10, 
1.1.11,
1.1.2, 
.......
```

Any help on how to sort it so that 1.1.10 is coming after 1.1.9?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how many record do you have? (I'm curious if you could hold all of them in memory to sort them)

Comment: it is only less than 400 records with 8 fields in each record. Currently, I am using order by in mysql query. But the order of the COA is bad since 1.1.10 is coming before 1.1.2

Answer (score 3):

This is ugly, but it will work:

```
ORDER
   BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT( col ,'.'),'.',1) + 0
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT( col ,'.'),'.',2),'.',-1) + 0
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT( col ,'.'),'.',3),'.',-1) + 0
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT( col ,'.'),'.',4),'.',-1) + 0
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT( col ,'.'),'.',5),'.',-1) + 0
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT( col ,'.'),'.',6),'.',-1) + 0
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT( col ,'.'),'.',7),'.',-1) + 0
```

To test these expressions, you can use them in a SELECT and verify they extract the right components, and they are ordered correctly:

```
SELECT col
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT( col ,'.'),'.',1) + 0 AS p1
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT( col ,'.'),'.',2),'.',-1) + 0 AS p2
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT( col ,'.'),'.',3),'.',-1) + 0 AS p3
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT( col ,'.'),'.',4),'.',-1) + 0 AS p4
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT( col ,'.'),'.',5),'.',-1) + 0 AS p5
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT( col ,'.'),'.',6),'.',-1) + 0 AS p6
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT( col ,'.'),'.',7),'.',-1) + 0 AS p7
  FROM mytable 
 ORDER BY 2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

---

Rather than explain how this works, i'm just going to hit the important "tricks"

- append a trailing "." on the end of the col, you need that so you don't get back the last position multiple times,
- use SUBSTRING_INDEX to retrieve portion up to nth '.'
- use SUBSTRING_INDEX to retrieve trailing portion of that (reading backwards, to the leading dot
- add zero, to convert the string to a numeric value

Comment: Sorry to bring up an old answer, but I was wondering why you `CONCAT` a decimal to the end of the `col`. The inner `SUBSTRING_INDEX` will get the substring up to and **excluding** the the Xth decimal point, and the outer `SUBSTRING_INDEX` return everything to the right of (and **excluding**) the first decimal, counting from the right. That should just give you a number value. So I don't see the point in concatenating a decimal.

Comment: I added a trailing dot character because of quirkiness with `SUBSTRING_INDEX`.  To demonstrate, `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('1.2','.',4),'.',-1)` returns `2`. (Replacing 4 with any integer 2 or larger, and we get `2` back. If we concatenate a trailing dot character `1.2.` then we'll get back an empty string.  I was thinking in terms of sorting values with a variable number of dots, and I wanted `1.3` to sort before `1.3.1`. Without the extra dot added to `1.3`, the ORDER BY expressions would evaluate to '1','3','3','3','3',...  which would cause `1.3` to be sorted *after* `1.3.1`.

Comment: (cont.) By adding a trailing dot character, so we operate on `'1.3.'`, the order by expressions return '1','3','0','0','0'.  And that's what I wanted: to return zeros for p3, p4, p5,... when those components are missing. This may not be strictly necessary. But in the general case... where we want to sort `'3'` and `'3.1.4.2'`... I wanted to handle 3 as if if was `3.0.0.0`. See it in action by running the SELECT. (My solution is more general, and works for more than just the examples in the OP case, having the exact same number of dots. A later comment from OP on another answer has more dots.)

Comment: ah ok thanks for explaining. That makes sense. And I just now noticed that you already explained it in your answer. Sorry for making you explain again.

Comment: @KodosJohnson: not a problem; the answer only grazed over the part about appending an extra dot character, without explaining why I did that. For some use cases, like every value in the column having the same number of dots in all the values, appending the dot won't make any difference. It only makes a difference sorting values with that have different numbers of dots.

Answer (score 2):

Assign the values to array and use [natsort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) to sort the values naturally.

```
$foo = array ('1.1.1', '1.1.2', '1.1.10', '1.1.11');
natsort ($foo);
print_r ($foo);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => 1.1.1
    [1] => 1.1.2
    [2] => 1.1.10
    [3] => 1.1.11
)
*/

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pull out the digits between the decimals and treat them as numerics. Use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to pull out the digits and [`CAST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) to turn them into numerics:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM myAccounts
ORDER BY
  CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(account_number, '.', 1) AS UNSIGNED),
  CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(account_number, '.', -2) AS UNSIGNED),
  CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(account_number, '.', -1) AS UNSIGNED)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT col FROM mytable ORDER BY REPLACE(col, ".", "")+0
```

`REPLACE` remove `.` and MySQL automatically converts the string with a mathematical operation. You can try `REPLACE(col, ".", "")*1`

Answer (score 0):

if the sorting field is `name` then use the following `ORDER BY` clause

```
ORDER BY length(name), name
```

Comment: To make this thing complicated, it can be like this as well, 2.5.1.1, 2.5.2.1,...... 2.5.10.1, 2.5.10.2, 2.5.11.1, ....... Human has no problem in sorting it but, application? can we do it? my friend suggested to have one more field called order to define the order of the accounts. But maintaining this order would be very troublesome.....

Comment: then your best option is to introduce a sort order field

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I've managed it as the following:

```
SELECT .... , CAST(SUBSTRING([column_name],1) AS UNSIGNED) AS myNum,  CAST(SUBSTRING([column_name],3) AS UNSIGNED) AS myDec
FROM ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY myNum, myDec
```

In your case maybe you will need an additional "depth".
Hope this helps you to get some insight.