# Sorting a "1.1.1" format type in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I want to Sort this type 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 2.1, 2.1.1, 2.3,..etc. like this i am using Varchar datatype for this Column But what happens is it sort proper till 9.9.9 after this 10.1.1 here sorting happens like this 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, **10.1.1,** 2.1, 2.1.1,...etc. like this I also tried using DECIMAL but no results.

Comment: At time of insertion in the db create one more column like unique_id which will be unique and can be used for sorting at the time of retrieval.

Comment: As a hack, you can use INET_ATON and INET_NTOA

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508313/mysql-sorting-of-version-numbers and note that all solutions using a function to sort the result can't use an index so it is likely to be slow. If performance is crtical consider storing each part of the string as separate columns so they can be indexed.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse value into three different columns, not nessesary in your database, application code will do it more easily. Then it becomes as simple as

```
select ... order by col1, col2, col3
```

Answer (score 0):

A good idea would be to store your number as fixed size, e.g.

- 1.1.1 => 001001001 (or in short 1001001)
- 1.1   => 1001000
- 9.9.9 => 9009009

This way you can store your variable as number. Upon retrieval, you will have to play with modulo to set your number back to string. The main limitation will be you will have to decide how many are available for each segment (in my example 999 is the max for each segment.
This method is how I store IP adress i want to sort (e.g. 192.168.1.1 becomes 192168001001).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    my_table
ORDER BY 
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(my_col, '.', 1) AS UNSIGNED) ASC,
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(my_col, '.', -2), '.', 1) AS UNSIGNED) ASC,
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(my_col, '.', -1) AS UNSIGNED) ASC
```

Basically it gets the substring of each part of the string, and sorts the rows by using each part of the string, going from left to right.

**Update:** The above query works for exactly 3 numbers. But if you want to support 4 numbers, then use this query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    my_table
ORDER BY 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(my_col, '.'), '.', 1), '.', -1) + 0
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(my_col, '.'), '.', 2), '.', -1) + 0
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(my_col, '.'), '.', 3), '.', -1) + 0
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(my_col, '.'), '.', 4), '.', -1) + 0
```

And if you want to support more numbers, just add the following, replacing "XX" with the next number:

```
, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(my_col, '.'), '.', XX), '.', -1) + 0
```

Credit to this answer on a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17849200/2518200

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply i tried with this but still sorting doesn't getting proper Result. 

result getting From Above query:
7.3.1.1, 7.3.1.2, 7.3.1.4, 7.3.2.2, 7.2.4, 12.2.1, 12.2

result Desire
7.2.4, 7.3.1.1, 7.3.1.2, 7.3.1.4, 7.3.2.2, 12.2, 12.2.1

Comment: @Jaineshshah Sorry, that query was for 3 numbers. Since you have up to 4 numbers or more, I had to change my answer. Please see my updated answer. You can use this new query for any length.